# CSS images not copied to output folder in Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I am using Webpack to bundle a number of js/css files in a site.  I am bundling bootstrap.css and [chosen.css](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) as part of my bundles.  In order to create the bundles, I have a main.js that I am using as an entry point to import all the other files that I will need.  I am using file-loader to process font and image files and move them to the appropriate directories.  I am using the [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) with the [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) and [resolve-url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader) to create a separate css bundle from my js bundle.

My main.js is:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'chosen-js/chosen.css';
import './datetimehelper.js';
import './deletelink.js';
import './dropdown.js';
```

My webpack.config.js is:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'wwwroot/js/bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'wwwroot/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'wwwroot/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader?url=false', 'resolve-url-loader'],
          publicPath: '../'
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'wwwroot/css/bundle.css'
    })
  ]
};
```

With the above configuration, the font references in bootstrap.css are picked up, moved to the appropriate directory and the urls are fixed in the css bundle that is emitted.  However, the images that are referenced in chosen.css are not being picked up.  Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make the images work correctly?  I've tried replacing file-loader with url-loader and no change.  I've also tried importing the images in my main.js and they were moved, but the urls in the css bundle were not rewritten correctly.

Comment: are the files being output in the wwwroot/images folder?

Comment: No, they are not.  I got them to output by including each individual image in main.js, but the url() references in chosen.css were still not corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Having `path` configured in `output` makes life a lot easier. That would serve as the base output folder and all other loaders/plugins can work relative to that. May be the files were copied but not to your intended directory. Please do take a look at [WebpackBootstrap repo](https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-bootstrap). The config copies as well as converts image paths properly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  In the rules, I had:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader')
}
```

Instead, it should be:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: ExtratTextPlugin.extract('css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader')
}
```

Not sure what the difference is between `use` and `loader` because I'm fairly new to Webpack, but in this case it makes all the difference.